# How to prevent Firefox tracking protection from blocking flickr-images I inserted dynamically with javascript?

Tags: firefox, cross-domain, block, tracking

Locally I have apache running, calling http://home/s.html 
There by Javascript I fetch the xml-file from a flickr-search. I visually want to represent the search, by inserting html in the s.html-page.

The images are all blocked.
Random example for blocked file: https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8120/29612550501_6162ed8901_n.jpg

This is adressed in other questions here on stackoverflow, but not really answered for the following detail:

> Is it possible to somehow circumvent the tracking protection using
>   Javascript?

P.S. Firefox seems to use a protection list organized by disconnect.me 
This list is really running wild! It even blocks the small avatar-images (under https://secure.gravatar.com) that are used on the Bugzilla website itself! (Random example page: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1101005) On a more philosophical view, I wonder if the Firefox developers browse themselves with strict tracking protection, and therefore see their own bugzilla-website slightly broken?

I will post on this topic on superuser, but with an approriate question for superuser. Here I only want to know, if it possible for me to circumvent that blocking with my javascript!

Comment: If flickr allows CORS and tracking protection only blocks loads that would send cookies, origin or referrers you *might* be able to use `fetch()` to load those via anonymous requests. But those are big ifs. As for the breakage, that is considered acceptable collateral damage. Gravatar can track your browsing habits since it's included in many sites.